# 'Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1' error when attempting to fit lines

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

The code is two separate data into two separate straight lines and determine which configuration has the best fitting

```
def straight_line(x,m,c):
 return  m*x + c

def sep_point(x,y):
  seperation = 2
  r_sqr = []

  while seperation < len(x):
    
    x_1 = x[:seperation]
    y_1 = y[:seperation]
    x_2 = x[seperation:]
    y_2 = y[seperation:]
    
    popt_1 ,pcov_1 = curve_fit(straight_line, x_1, y_1) 
    popt_2 ,pcov_2 = curve_fit(straight_line, x_2, y_2)
    
    res_1 = y_1 - straight_line(x_1, *popt_1)
    res_2 = y_2 - straight_line(x_2, *popt_2)
    
    res_sqr_1 = np.sum(res_1**2)
    res_sqr_2 = np.sum(res_2**2)
    
    ss_1 = np.sum((y_1-np.mean(y_1))**2)
    ss_2 = np.sum((y_2-np.mean(y_2))**2)
    
    r_sqr_1 = 1 - (res_sqr_1 / ss_1)
    r_sqr_2 = 1 - (res_sqr_2 / ss_2)
    
    r_sqr.append(r_sqr_1 * r_sqr_2)
    seperation += 1
  return (r_sqr)
```

Then I get this Traceback error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-638d4928b679> in <module>
----> 1 test = sep_point(decelleration_voltage[:-1],lnRevColdShieldI[:-1])

 <ipython-input-41-7aa65ea99d01> in sep_point(x, y)
      10 
      11         popt_1 ,pcov_1 = curve_fit(straight_line, x_1, y_1)
 ---> 12         popt_2 ,pcov_2 = curve_fit(straight_line, x_2, y_2)
      13 
      14         res_1 = y_1 - straight_line(x_1, *popt_1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma,            absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
742         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
743         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 744         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
745         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
746         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun,    full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
385     m = shape[0]
386     if n > m:
--> 387         raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
388     if epsfcn is None:
389         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

TypeError: Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1
```

(Note: The last piece of data is cut off on the input to stop an 'inf' value which doesn't work

Comment: What is the length of your `x` and `y` variables? If it is 3, the error is caused by the fact that `x2` and `y2` then contain only a single value, and you cannot fit a function with two parameters using only a single data point. In the error, `N` indicates the number of parameters to fit, and `M` the number of data points used to fit the parameters. `M` should be greater than or equal to `N`.

Comment: That's it exactly thank you! I changed it to '<(len(x)-2)' and it all worked